# What is the correct way of loading values from file during application startup?

Tags: c#, xml

I've certain values stored in an xml file. These values are to be read at the time of application startup and should be available to all other classes. The structure of xml is as follows:

```
<Values>
    <Tag1>Value1</Tag1>
    <Tag2>Value2</Tag2>
    <Tag3>Value3</Tag3>
</Value>
```

They should be read only once  and that too at the time of startup. If after the application has started and has read all the values, the values are changed by some means, then, it should not affect the values which the application has read. I mean to say that it should not be like whenever a class object demands a value at runtime, everytime xml is read and the value is retrived.

My first question is:
Is this a good practice?

If yes, then,

What is the best way to do this in C#?

I found out that a static class which contain static members for all the values and a static method which writes the values to these members would solve the purpose.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        string strPath = "";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(strPath);
        Reader.ReadXml(doc.SelectSingleNode("/Values/Tag1").InnerText,doc.SelectSingleNode("/Values/Tag2").InnerText,doc.SelectSingleNode("/Values/Tag3").InnerText);
        Application.Run(new class1());
    }
}

public static class Reader
{
    public static string str1;
    public static string str2;
    public static string str3;

    private static void ReadXml(string s1, string s2, string s3)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(strXmlPath);
        str1 = s1;
        str2 = s2;
        str3 = s3;
    }
}

class xyz
{        
    string GetValue()
    {
        return Reader.str1;
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried. Is this the right way of handling this scenario? Please enlighten me about the right approach in this situation.

Moreover, if the number of values is more then, shall I pass that many variables?

Comment: I would disagree with that being "fine" - global state (those static fields) - is rarely a good idea. I would read the XML into some sort of Configuration instance, and either pass the whole configuration into whatever needs it, or even better just the relevant parts. Look into Dependency Injection.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using app.config? It already supports exactly what you seem to want to do here (check Nacho's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, is fine, but if this values are the application configuration you can put this in the web.config file and use `ConfigurationManager` to get this values. (you can use section in the configuration file too).

For example:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="nameKey1" value="Value1"/>
<add key="nameKey2" value="Value2"/>
<add key="nameKey3" value="Value3"/>
</appSettings>
```

and call this:

```
string key1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["nameKey1"];
```

I hope I have been helpful

(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really wrong with the arrangement you did but I'd change a few things about it - most of that is to hide away details of how data is acquired by the program.

I would separater out the reader object and application setting data - as applications grow, they tend to have more and more settings so code for reading and storing the data tends to grow. You may also - in the future - want to some other data source (database, network service, etc.) instead of and XML file. If you keep the setting reader and the setting data tied together, it's harder to make those changes.

First I'd create an interface to define a setting reader:

```
public interface ISettingReader
{
    int ReadSomeAppInt ();

    // TODO add other read functions
}
```

You can then implement this interface in a number of ways:

```
public class XmlAppSettingReader : ISettingReader
{
    public XmlAppSettingReader ( string sFilename )
    {
        // TODO open XML file and get ready to read settings
    }

    public int ReadSomeAppInt ()
    {
        // TODO read the named integer from XML and return it
    }
}
```

If necessary, you can also implement this for a database, etc.

Then I'd create some kind of a static setting class (for example, `GlobalSettings`, etc.) that would do nothing but store and return application-wide setting values. This class would also have an `Init` function to initialize its values at pplication startup from a designated setting reader.

```
public static class GlobalSettings
{
    // TODO add public static get properties for various settings
    private static int s_nSomeAppInt;

    public static void Init ( ISettingReader oReader )
    {
        // TODO use reader to read individual setting values

        int nSomeAppInt = oReader.ReadSomeAppInt ();

        // TODO validate nSomeAppInt and store it in private
        // static field
        s_nSomeAppInt = nSomeAppInt;
    }

    public static int SomeAppInt
    {
        get
        {
            return ( s_nSomeAppInt );
        }
    }
}
```

You can then load settings in your `Main` function:

```
{
    ISettingReader oReader = new XmlAppSettingReader ( "C:\file.xml" );
    GlobalSettings.Init ( oReader );

    // TODO continue startup
}
```

This setup allows you to handle loading application settings and serving them to internal components independent of each other. You can change either without affecting the other easily.

To further refine this (as commented by Jon Skeet) make `GlobalSettings` non-static and implement its own `IGlobalSettings` interface. Then each application component would receive an `IGlobalSettings` reference and read settings from that object instead of trying to access a global static object.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml is in a serialized format like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfValues xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Values>
        <Tag1>Value1</Tag1>
        <Tag2>Value2</Tag2>
        <Tag3>Value3</Tag3>
    </Values>
</ArrayOfValues>
```

And you have a class in which you want to deserialize like below:

```
public class Values
{
    // set the types accordingly
    public string Tag1 { get; set; }
    public string Tag2 { get; set; }
    public string Tag3 { get; set; }
}
```

Moreover, you may have a class that would contain the deserialized code inside of it:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Serialization
{
    public class ValuesGenerator
    {
        private const string XmlPath = "SPECIFY THE XML FULL PATH HERE";

        public List<Values> GetColumnInfo()
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Values>));
            return (List<Values>)serializer.Deserialize(new StreamReader(XmlPath));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can deserialize it at the beginning of your program like below:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        // look for the following 2 lines
        var valuesGenerator = new ValuesGenerator();
        List<Values> values = valuesGenerator.GetColumnInfo(); // This is the list which contains the deserialized info

        Application.Run(new class1());
    }
}
```